# what is the order of column while querying using contentresolver in db?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I have a table structure

```
      table(col1 char,col2 int,col3 int,col4 char,col5 char) .
```

i am using the content resolver to query  for column (col1,col4,col3).

to access the particular column i am using

```
   cursor.getstring(curso.getColumnIndex('col1'))
```

i am getting the values properly for this approach.

but if  i use the column index values  to access

```
cursor.getstring(1) it is not giving the column col4(1st position).
```

The order of the resultant column is neither in querying order nor in table structure order

it is like ( col3,col1,col4).

it is returning in different order by content resolver.why this is behavior is like this? how can we use the index acces for this? and reliability